# customize the ABPersonPickerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios4

How can we customize the ABPeoplePickerNavigationViewController to display FullName in the first line and email,phone number in the next line. This should not happen on a contact select but should default when the ABPickerController view is loaded.

What I want is the regular functionalities of the ABPeoplePicker.. but the contacts display should have additional information explained above.

I think I would have to extend the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would want the ABPeoplePicker.... and the addressBook to work together dont quite have a solution.Tried the same thing but finally we spun out a new custom indexed table view. Was quite easy.
if you want an indexed tableView created please have a look at
[indexed-ui-tableview](http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/)

you could then change the following method for having information in multiple lines.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] 
                       objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", @"someone@gmail.com", @"|",@"123456777777777777777"] ;;

return cell;
```

}

The data generator can be modified to accomodate your model.
the email etc can be obtained from your model.In the snippet above it is hard coded.You could then easily wire in the search functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
// assigning control back to the main controller
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
NSString *firstname=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
Usernametf.text=firstname;
 ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMultiValueRef addressProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
NSArray *address = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(addressProperty);

      NSString* phone;
     phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
     phoneNotf.text=phone;
     //NSLog(@"%@",phone);

if([address count] > 0)
{
    for (NSDictionary *addressDict in address)
    {
      NSString*  countrytf = [addressDict objectForKey:@"Country"];
      NSString*  streetaddresstf= [addressDict objectForKey:@"Street"];
      NSString*  citynametf = [addressDict objectForKey:@"City"];
      NSString*  statenametf = [addressDict objectForKey:@"State"];
       NSString* zipcodetf = [addressDict objectForKey:@"ZIP"];
    }
    CFRelease(addressProperty);
}

  //  NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:firstname,@"FirstName", nil];
//[selectedemailArray addObject:dict];
// NSLog(@"\n array is %@",selectedemailArray);


//[objDatabase insertArray:selectedemailArray forTable:@"EmailList"];
//[objDatabase insertDictionary:dict forTable:@"EmailList"];
 //    [dict release];
  //    dict =nil;

// remove the controller
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;

 }

 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
return NO;
 }
```

here is whole code where you can get anything from contacts.

let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: thanx for ur valuable reply . But as i've mentioned in my question i want to display name , email and contact number on the same cell for a particular  contact before selection. In the detault table view display. The table cell would thus say 
        
        David Bothom
        david@gmail.com, 9972543212

        Sachin Tendulkar
        sachin@yahoo.com, 8767542109